# setTimeout classlist add/remove very erratic

Tags: javascript, html

I want to leverage `setTimeout()` to add and remove classes, but in my current implementation the behavior is very erratic. See below:

```js
  let topBars = document.querySelectorAll(".bar");
  function clearClasses() {
    topBars.forEach((bar, i) => {
      topBars[i].classList.remove('active-bar')
    })
  }
  function cycleBars() {
    topBars.forEach((bar, i) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("the index is: " + i)
        clearClasses()
        topBars[i].classList.add('active-bar')
      }, i * 5000)
    })
  }
  if (topBars.length > 1) {
    setInterval(cycleBars, 5000);
  }
```

```css
  .active-bar {
    color: red;
    background-color: black;
  }
```

```html
<div class="bar active-bar">FISRT</div>
<div class="bar">SECOND</div>
<div class="bar">THIRD</div>
```

The behavior is all over the place and it seems to be skipping sometimes and other times not. The idea is to have a class toggle down based on a delayed loop, taken from this idea here: https://travishorn.com/delaying-foreach-iterations-2ebd4b29ad30

What is going wrong here, and howcome it seems to be jumping around inconsistently?

Comment: `setInterval()` kicks off a repeating process, just like a loop and for that reason, the loop is redundant and the source of your problem because, within it, you are then kicking off a number of new timers. This is a common misunderstanding of how to use timers to do something repeatedly. You don't need a loop to accomplish your task, the `setInterval()` essentially creates a loop.

Comment: @ScottMarcus `setInterval` isn't called within a loop anywhere. OP, the problem is that `clearClasses` applies to all elements, but is being called for each element.

Comment: @robinsax: agree with you, please write an answer.

Comment: @robinsax You misunderstand what I'm saying. When you have an interval (or a recursive timeout), you effectively create looping code. Adding loops in the callbacks of those timers will just run the entire loop with no delay between iterations. When something like this use case is desired, the timer's callback essentially runs as if it was the loop body - - no loops are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation of what Scott Marcus mentioned in the comments:

```js
let topBars = document.querySelectorAll(".bar");
let activeBarIndex = 0;
function cycleBars() {
  topBars[activeBarIndex].classList.remove('active-bar');
  ++activeBarIndex;
  if (activeBarIndex >= topBars.length) {
     activeBarIndex = 0;
  }
  topBars[activeBarIndex].classList.add('active-bar');
}

if (topBars.length > 1) {
  setInterval(cycleBars, 5000);
}
```

```css
  .active-bar {
    color: red;
    background-color: black;
  }
```

```html
<div class="bar active-bar">FIRST</div>
<div class="bar">SECOND</div>
<div class="bar">THIRD</div>
```

setInterval() causes cycleBars() to be called every five seconds.

Comment: Yeah, I saw versions of this, this seems definitely the better route...

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with setTimeout in cycleBars function, that should give you your solution.

If you set setTimeouts delay in cycleBars to 1000ms it runs as it should, so what happens you skip some numbers because it itterates twice in a row if you put the same amout of delay on setInterval and setTimeout.

Here:

```
let delay = 15000;

let topBars = document.querySelectorAll(".bar");
  function clearClasses() {
    topBars.forEach((bar, i) => {
      topBars[i].classList.remove('active-bar')
    })
  }
  function cycleBars() {
    topBars.forEach((bar, i) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("the index is: " + i)
        clearClasses()
        topBars[i].classList.add('active-bar')
      }, i * (delay/topBars.length))
    })
  }
  if (topBars.length > 1) {
    setInterval(cycleBars, delay);
  }
```

Idealy you would add delay in ms to a variable, and attach that variable to setInterval and setTimeout delay parameter

Comment: right, so setting that to 1000 does fix it, but it's too fast. I want the delay to be 5000. Howcome adding 5000 breaks it?

Comment: Edited the solution, check it out

Comment: If you want it to be 5 seconds each change delays to 15000

Comment: the behavior is still erratic, it's not consistently going 1 > 2 > 3

Comment: I edited once again, let me explain what happens. If you set the delay in setTimeout to be exactly the same as setInterval then you call whats in setTimeout and setInterval at the same time and what you get is skipping numbers and that is what gives you that behaviour. Unless you divide setTimeout delay with number of itterations it goes through. https://codepen.io/darioKolic/pen/eYZjEdQ